# How to resolve an error near NULL when creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Whenever I try to create a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE registration` (`id` INT NOT NULL , `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , `email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `password` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL , `DOB` DATE NOT NULL , `age` INT NOT NULL , `number` BIGINT NOT NULL , `religion` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL , `education` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `profession` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `gender` ENUM NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The following error occurs

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 1

Comment: If you formatted your SQL, with line breaks and white space, you would likely find this easier to fix, as everything wouldn't be on line 1.

Comment: You really do NOT want to store passwords in clear text. You need to salt and hash your passwords which means they will require a bit more storage than 15 characters.

Comment: Just a note, if you are lucky enough to be in a MS environment, you can install MS Workbench for free, and its a GUI for your MYSQL.  Right click to create a table, then set the columns and primary key with that.  If you are automating stuff, inline is great, but if you are manually doing stuff, Workbench will be your new best friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ENUM needs values so you need to define the values they can get

```
CREATE TABLE registration (
    `id` INT NOT NULL 
    , `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
    , `email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    , `password` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL 
    , `DOB` DATE NOT NULL 
    , `age` INT NOT NULL 
    , `number` BIGINT NOT NULL 
    , `religion` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL 
    , `education` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    , `profession` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    , `gender` ENUM ('male','female')
 , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a ENUM column (your gender column) you have to assign all possible values for the enumeration ([See here for syntax](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-enum#:%7E:text=The%20ENUM%20data%20type%20in,of%20the%20specified%20possible%20values.))